Need to iterate a hash returned from a mysql query
Ok - I have the following member function:
sub GetCategories {
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT CatID, CatName, CatLink FROM Categories");
    $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
    my $results = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
    return($results);
    $sth->finish();
}

I call it with:
my $Cats = $d2s->GetCategories();

my $vars = my $vars = {
    categories => $Cats,
};

However my question is, how do I drill through that and extract the values in perl?
It is driving me nuts - below is the format of the $vars data from Data::Dumper -
$VAR1 = {
      'categories' => \[
                          [
                            1,
                            'General',
                            './PostList.pl?cat=General'
                          ],
                          [
                            2,
                            'DevOps',
                            './PostList.pl?cat=DevOps'
                          ]
     };

I expected to see
 'categories' => [ { 'CatID' => 1, 'CatLink' => './PostList.pl?cat=General', 
'CatName' => 'General' }, { 'CatID' => 2, 'CatLink' => './PostList.pl?cat=DevOps', 'CatName' => 'DevOps' }, 

and so on
how do I for example print out the value for example DevOps in the second structure in a perl script. I can do it in a tt template just not perl

If you return from the sub, the last line $sth->finish() is never executed. The return should be the last line in your sub (in this case). Also, your code contains some weird backticks. If that is not in your actual code, it should not be in this code. You should fix that, if it is a typo.

The code you have shown does not produce the output you show. Did you really pass an empty hashref as an argument like fetchall_arrayref({})? This should return one hashref per row. Also your Dumper output shows a reference to an arrayref. Your code does not produce that.

If a variable contains a reference, you need to dereference it to access the referenced thing.
my $VAR1 = {
    categories => \[
                      [
                        1,
                        'General',
                        './PostList.pl?cat=General'
                      ],
                      [
                        2,
                        'DevOps',
                        './PostList.pl?cat=DevOps'
                      ]
                  ]  # <- this was missing in your code!
};
print ${ $VAR1->{categories} }->[1][1];  # DevOps

$VAR1 is a hash reference, we can dereference it using the arrow.
$VAR1->{categories}

The value associated with "categories" is a reference to an array reference, so we need to dereference it as a scalar to get an array reference
${ $VAR1->{categories} }

then we can use the arrow again to get into the array.
${ $VAR1->{categories} }->[1]

BTW, if the $sth->finish(); is placed after a return, it will never be executed.

"he value associated with "categories" is a reference to an array reference, so we need to dereference it as a scalar to get an array reference"
That is exactly what I do not know how to do. Do you have an example of how to do it?
BTW: I've only been learning perl for less than a month but I've been writing bash scripts for a long time, so far I'm loving perl

It's shown in the last line of the code sample. Read about references in Mark's very short tutorial about references and Perl references and nested data structures

The code you show for GetCategories() is designed to return an Arrayref of Hashrefs. Note the use of an empty hashref as argument to fetchall_arrayref({}) which is documented here (If $slice is a hash reference, fetchall_arrayref fetches each row as a hash reference) . However the rest of your question shows a structure that was not created by that code.
Here is a complete example that demonstrates the use of fetchall_arrayref({}) and how to access a specific element in the returned structure (sorry, its postgres, but that does not make a difference here):
use 5.030;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBD::Pg;
my $sql =q|
SELECT * FROM
(VALUES( 1,
        'General',
        './PostList.pl?cat=General'),
       ( 2,
         'DevOps',
         './PostList.pl?cat=DevOps')
)AS categories("CatID", "CatName", "CatLink")|; 


my $dh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:Pg:dbname=postgres; host=127.0.0.1", "postgres");
die $DBI::errstr unless $dh;
my $sth = $dh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
my $res = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
    
print Dumper $res;

foreach (@$res)
{
    print "ID: $_->{'CatID'}<br>NAME: $_->{'CatName'}<br>LINK: $_->{CatLink}<br><br>\n";
} 

prints:
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'CatID' => 1,
            'CatName' => 'General',
            'CatLink' => './PostList.pl?cat=General'
          },
          {
            'CatLink' => './PostList.pl?cat=DevOps',
            'CatName' => 'DevOps',
            'CatID' => 2
          }
        ];
ID: 1<br>NAME: General<br>LINK: ./PostList.pl?cat=General<br><br>
ID: 2<br>NAME: DevOps<br>LINK: ./PostList.pl?cat=DevOps<br><br>


Good explanation (I think you meant use DBI, not use DBD::Pg)

I used DBD::Pg which pulls in DBI but as i wrote, this is a pg example, it will work with mysql as well.

Interesting. I've always followed the DBI and DBD::Pg docs, which suggest this: ```use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname", ...); # OR
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbname", ...)


It should work either way. Except if you use DBI it will die at runtime when DBD::Pg is not installed . With use DBD::Pg it dies during compilation - which makes no difference here.

Of course. The DBD::XX driver module has to be installed, but is very rarely explicitly useed in my experience with DBI. ymmv

I came a cropper if this recently with cpan refusing to install because it required Mysql >= V8.I was using MariaDB and the most recent version of DBD::mysql failed . Now I install DBD::mysql or DBD::MariaDB depending on what server I'm on then in my code just 'use DBI;'

@clamp - Am I being stupid or is de-referencing a variable in perl very similar to Type Casting?

Read about references and dereferencing here: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref

I'll try that later.
I achieved what I need to by the following, but it's not ideal, once I get my head round perl references and variable scoping I'll follow your advice because it looks more compact and generic, which is what I want.
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
    my @arrRtn;
    my $i=0;

  while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
    my ($cat_id, $cat_name, $cat_link ) = @row;
    @arrRtn[$i] = {
        'CatID'  => $cat_id,
        'CatName' => $cat_name,
        'CatLink' => $cat_link,
    };
    $i++;
}
      
$sth->finish();
#print Dumper(@hRtn);
foreach (@arrRtn)
{
    print "ID: $_->{'CatID'}<br>NAME: $_->{'CatName'}<br>LINK: $_->{CatLink}<br><br>";
} 


You can replace the while loop using fetchall_arrayref({}). See my updated answer.

Hi thanks for the advice, I knew it was down to my lack of exposure to perl.:-)

Thanks for all your help, I had to go away and learn perl types
I knew it was down to my lack of exposure to perl.I have this now and it works a treat
my $results = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
my @resArr = @{$results};

  for my $rec (@resArr)
  {
      print 
            $rec->{'CatID'} . "\r\n" .
            $rec->{'CatName'} . "\r\n" .
            $rec->{'CatLink'} . "\r\n\r\n";
  }

